# A very very strange CSS/ASP.NET bug

Tags: asp.net, css, themes

I created a basic style sheet for layout and text size and several ASP.Net themes for style. For some reason, every other menu element is working except the "My Account" element. Even the sub-menu items are working properly.

[image: Screenshot of strange CSS bug]

```
/*Basic CSS menu Layout*/
#Menu
{
    font-size: 24pt;
    height: 48px;
    width: 1000px;
    color: White;
    background-color: Black;
}

#Menu a
{
    color: White;
    text-decoration: underline;
    width: 224px;
    height: 48px;
}

#Menu a:visited
{
    color: White;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#Menu a:hover
{
    color: White;
    font-style: italic;
}
/*StyleSheetTheme menu layout*/
#Menu a
{
    background-image: url('Menu_Default.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#Menu a:hover
{
    background-image: url('Menu_Default.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#Menu a:visited
{
    background-image: url('Menu_Default.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#Menu a:active
{
    background-image: url('Menu_Default.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Do you have some markup for this or are you using the ASP.NET menu control? If the menu is rendered by markup you've written yourself, it would be useful to see it to determine what might prevent the CSS selector from targeting your element.

Comment: How should it look, and what is it doing instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved! My error was a strange one, alright. It was in my sitemap; 2 out of 3 of my top-level menu items are not linked - they are categories. The sitemap scheme did not know how to translate the only top-level linked menu item. Let me show you the difference: between the old sitemap and the working sitemap:

CURRENT WORKING

```
      <siteMapNode>
          <siteMapNode url="Index.aspx" title="Home ☻" > </siteMapNode>
          <siteMapNode url="" title="Account ☻" >
              <siteMapNode url="Login.aspx" title="☻Login" />
              <siteMapNode url="Register.aspx" title="☻Register" />
              <siteMapNode url="EditAccount.aspx" title="☻Edit Profile" />
              <siteMapNode url="MyAccount.aspx" title="☻My Account" />
          </siteMapNode>
          <siteMapNode url="" title="About Me ☻">
              <siteMapNode url="GameDesign.aspx" title="☻App Design" />
              <siteMapNode url="WebDesign.aspx" title="☻Web Design" />
              <siteMapNode url="Contact.aspx" title="☻Contact Me" />
          </siteMapNode>
          <siteMapNode title="Freebies ☻ ">
              <siteMapNode url="FreeGames.aspx" title="☻Games"/>
              <siteMapNode url="FreeGraphics.aspx" title="☻Graphics" />
              <siteMapNode url="TipsnTrix.aspx" title="☻Design Tips" />
          </siteMapNode>
      </siteMapNode>
```

OLD

```
      <siteMapNode>
          <siteMapNode url="Index.aspx" title="Home ☻" > </siteMapNode>
          <siteMapNode url="MyAccount.aspx" title="Account ☻" >
              <siteMapNode url="Login.aspx" title="☻Login" />
              <siteMapNode url="Register.aspx" title="☻Register" />
              <siteMapNode url="EditAccount.aspx" title="☻Edit Profile" />
          </siteMapNode>
          <siteMapNode url="" title="About Me ☻">
              <siteMapNode url="GameDesign.aspx" title="☻App Design" />
              <siteMapNode url="WebDesign.aspx" title="☻Web Design" />
              <siteMapNode url="Contact.aspx" title="☻Contact Me" />
          </siteMapNode>
          <siteMapNode title="Freebies ☻ ">
              <siteMapNode url="FreeGames.aspx" title="☻Games"/>
              <siteMapNode url="FreeGraphics.aspx" title="☻Graphics" />
              <siteMapNode url="TipsnTrix.aspx" title="☻Design Tips" />
          </siteMapNode>
      </siteMapNode>
```

What a crazy error! I didn't know you could mess up your sitemsp's schema like that! Lesson learned; be consistent in your sitemap files; if you have linked submenus and top-level categories, make sure ALL of your top-level menu items are categories and ALL of your submenus are linked.

Answer (score 1):

Is the italicized text the 'bug'?
Is this while hovering to expand the menu? Here is your culprit;

**`font-style: italic;`**